# Problems with .htaccess with spaces

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess, it should hide .php, but it has probably problems with this url
www.webpage.com/index.php?msg=some msg with spaces
Could it be fixed?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

EDIT:

www.mysite.com/message.php?msg=You%20are%20logged%20in%20your%20rid%20is:8

In page I just wrote the content of msg: $_GET["msg"]:

> You are logged in your rid is:DOCTYPE htmlhtmlheadmeta charsetutf8 if
>   IEscript
>   srchttp:html5shiv.googlecode.comsvntrunkhtml5.jsscriptendiftitle ...

It wrotes the html document after, instead of rid which was passed there form session.

Comment: Spaces should be encoded as %20 or +, depending on where they are in the URL

Comment: A web server will never see spaces in a GET parameter. Either a modern browser will insert %20 where you have spaces, or if not a modern browser, the only part of the parameter the web server will see is the first word.

Comment: Well the problem was that, with this htaccess it added the %20 somewher into and then my web stopped working

Answer (score 1):

You need `NE` (no escape) flag in your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: This is indeed the solution to your problem. NE will stop further encoding of `%20` and when you do `$_GET['msg']` in your php code it will show value with space.

Comment: but it also add the inside part of html file, like I mentioned in edit

Comment: There is no way a rule can read source of your HTML and pass it to you. I am sure there is some issue in php code itself which I enhanced further.

Comment: but strange thing is that it do it only when I run mod rewrite, without htaccess it works fine

Comment: This is something I haven't seen before. Can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://domain.com/info` to check what you get.

Answer (score 0):

use QSA = Query String Append.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L, QSA]
```